# How to structure urls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-services

Currently my url structure in angularjs is as follows. When I load the page I use

```
Orders.query
```

and when I try to update using

```
order.update()
```

But once I put conditions like search and then fetch orders, update them using

```
order.update()
```

it tries to call PUT on conditioned/orders as the new orders are fetched using the Fetch factory method. Is there any better way to merge the urls to make it more meaningful. Is there any standard followed in this sort of cases?

```
angular.module('orders').factory('Orders', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('orders/:orderId', {
      orderId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]).factory('Search', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('search/orders/', {},{
      conditioned: {
        method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true
      }
    });
  }
])
```

Routes on server side(Expressjs) are

```
app.route('/orders')
  .get(orders.list)
  .post(users.requiresLogin, orders.create);

app.route('/orders/:orderId')
  .get(orders.read)
  .put(users.requiresLogin, orders.update)
  .delete(users.requiresLogin, orders.delete);

app.route('/search/orders')
  .get(orders.search);
```

Comment: Not sure I really understand what you are asking. What are conditioned orders? To fetch orders you would normally just perform a get on orders/

Comment: updated the question. should make more sense now

Comment: Why have search for? Why not just orders/

Comment: I want to have a GET url for search parameters and when I do orders/urlencodedsearchparams Server(Expressjs) looks for order with urlencodedsearchparams as orderId so had to create another url route

Comment: I'd try to rephrase the question as to what api you have and what each url returns and how it's used and then post what code you have done. What are the search parameters used for?

Comment: search params have page size, page number, few conditions, sort order

Comment: Normally I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/46jyohLe/ It's still not clear as to why you would have a get api that returns a page number because that's client side data

Comment: i meant cleint sends search params to server in the url. all the search params are provided by client to server

Comment: The url should really be just using something like /orders/?start-index=100&max-results=100